# I want to prevent from going back to login page , when im already login

Tags: php, laravel-5, authentication

how can i supposed to do that? i think i miss some queries . I hope you guys can help me with this. How to prevent user from going back to the login-page after successful login using back button . Because when I login in and pressed back im going back to my login page. Need help everyone. im using laravel framework

```
 public function login(Request $req)
 {
     $username=$req->input('email');
     $password=$req->input('password');
     $breadcrumb = 'Dashboard';
     $pageTitle = 'CollabUX | Dashboard';
     $prepath ='../';
     $currentURL = Req::url();

     $user = DB::table('add_users')->where(['username'=>$username,'password'=>$password])->get();    

     if(count($user)>0){
     // Store a piece of data in the session...
     session(['isloggedin' => 'true']);
     return View::make('dashboard')->with(
     array('breadcrumb' => $breadcrumb,'pageTitle' => $pageTitle,'currentURL' => $currentURL,'prepath' => $prepath));
 }
 else{
     //imbes na empty page, redirect ka ulit sa login page
     $data = array(
                   'error'  => 1,
                   'remarks' => 'Invalid Username/Password. Please try again.'
                    );
                    return View::make('login')->with('data', $data);
                }      
            }
```

Comment: In your login page, are you checking to see if the login session is true? If it is, then redirect somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `session_start()`
On the start of your home page add this line

`session_start()`
now on you login page do the following

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
     // redirect user to $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
 }
```

and in your login function after successful login do this

```
$_SESSION['user'] = //<user name of logged in user>
```

on logout do this

```
session_destroy()
```

`$_SESSION` array can hold any number of user defined values, you can use this to store all the data related to a session

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will take user to the last url, you might want to change it according to your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Simply do check your **login session** on **login form page**, if it is true then redirect them to their dashboard.

Comment: clear your cache then check, can you add your login form page code in question update plz,